# Grid view scrolling is not working in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I am developing an android application in my application I wanted to use **CollapsingToolbarLayout** and **GridView** in a same page.The **CollapsingToolBar** is working properly. But My **GridView Scrolling is not working.**

**activity_health.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_offer_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="akhil.com.d4d.activities.OfferDetails">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="#E7E7E7"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
<!--
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />-->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Rlayout_H_menus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/layoutmenu1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menu_offers"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                            android:scaleType="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/offer" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Offers"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    </LinearLayout>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menu_menu"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_offers"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                            android:scaleType="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/menu" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Menu"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    </LinearLayout>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menu_exchange"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_menu"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_exchange"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                            android:scaleType="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/exchange" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Exchange"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    </LinearLayout>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menu_health"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_exchange"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                            android:scaleType="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/health" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Health"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    </LinearLayout>




                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menu_less"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_health"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_less_more"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                            android:scaleType="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/less" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_less_more"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Less"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/layoutmenu2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutmenu1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menu_bank"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/menu_offers"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                            android:scaleType="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/bank" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Bank"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    </LinearLayout>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/menu_sos"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/menu_menu"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_bank"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/roundblue"
                            android:scaleType="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/sos" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="SOS"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/layoutImage"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutmenu2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!--
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/hospital_health"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>-->


                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:background="#FFF"
                        android:layout_height="150dp">
                    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                        android:id="@+id/indicator"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        app:centered="true"
                        app:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
                        app:snap="false" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>




        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <akhil.com.d4d.common.ExpandableHeightGridView
                android:id="@+id/health_grid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#E7E7E7"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:layout_weight="1">
</akhil.com.d4d.common.ExpandableHeightGridView>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>






</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!--
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_health"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="akhil.com.d4d.activities.Health">





    </RelativeLayout>-->
```

Comment: why do you use 2 times the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` ?

Comment: I removed it from gridView but scrolling is not working

Comment: There may be issue with external library.Please use default grid view and check.